# Silverlight vs Flash for gathering System Information

Tags: silverlight, flash, hardware

Currently I am working on getting system information via a Silverlight Embedded Application tied with a Silverlight Desktop App (running in trusted mode), as this is the only method available to gather system information from a user without them tweaking their registry beforehand.

What I am wondering is if there is a more seemless way to gather system hardware information from Windows, silverlight would be fairly seemless but it requires that registry tweak in order to collect the data via a embedded app. Can Flash do this without a desktop component?

Mainly just looking for a way to in-browser fetch user system hardware information, RAM, CPU and etc. Obviously the user needs to grant permission, but something fully embedded would be awesome. Any suggestions?

Comment: The system information you can gather in Flash is very limited, my guess is you are better of with Silverlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you already have invested in Silverlight, I would say that you should take a look at Silverlight v5. 
It has much [improved p/invoke capabilities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2011/09/27/pinvoke-in-silverlight5-and-net-framework.aspx) that you can take advantage of.

For example: [Enumerating MIDI interfaces](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/09/20/enumerating-midi-interfaces-using-silverlight-5-pinvoke), [Getting monitor resolution](http://10rem.net/blog/2012/02/07/creating-big-silverlight-windows-and-getting-monitor-resolutions-and-positions-with-pinvoke) is some examples to get you started.